Succubus comes to Earth and falls in love with Doctor
I've been trying to find a movie which was about a succubus (kind of female demon from hell) and she somehow got out of hell I think and she met this guy who was a doctor working in a hospital and they fell in love...
I also remember she killed some cat or something (because apparently she had an urge to kill? IDK) and at the end there was a scene where the succubus had wings.
Now I'm not sure when exactly this movie came out but I would guess 90s or 80s. It was in color, if that helps. It was live-action (not anime) normal movie. 
This is just a guess but I think I read something about it years ago that it was shot (recorded) in Hungary or Romania (but I'm not sure about that).

@WillFeldman while it could very well be the same movie, I hesitate to call it a duplicate. the descriptions submitted are different enough, and with movie ID questions, questions searching for the same movie are acceptable, since there's so many different ways to describe them as to make searching this site difficult sometimes.

@TrishLing Not to speak of the fact that ID questions can't be searched at all anyway.

Could be Dark Angel: The Ascent (as posted in the other question)

A demoness from Hell, Veronica Iscariot, uninterested in tormenting
  the souls of damned sinners, ascends to the world above and finds our
  world full of evil and corruption. Veronica decides her mission in
  life is to punish the wicked and evil and goes about this with a
  bloody vengeance. Along the way she meets and falls in love with a
  doctor, Max Harris, who tends her wounds after an accident.

Trailer:




Thanks! I looked for it for looong time :D I checked imdb for every keyword etc multiple times before but you find it in matter of minutes! Youre awesome :D <3
